# Managing text in Android application like in a eBook

Tags: java, android

I am developing an `application` which looks like an eBook reader, but its not exactly an eBook reader.
I have a huge text which is divided into various chapters. Now i want to present that text as a book, user should get a feel of reading an eBook which will have various features like `GoTo`, Search, Table of Contents and most importantly page curl transition between pages.

Now the problem is how to divide the whole content into number of pages. How can I know that, the number of characters that are going to fit into the screen( depending on the screen size and font size). I am totally confused on where to start and how to proceed.

Ultimately I am planning to develop an eBook Reader which will read only one book that is the text which I give.

Please let me know to achieve this, where to put page breaks and where to put the text( in database or resource file).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224517/pagination-in-android-textview/6224666#6224666

Comment: did you find solution to this?

Comment: Regarding text pagination, take a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837840/paginating-text-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use Android `TextSwitcher` UI Component.

It automatically breaks the text according to the screen size. You can add some click listeners to traverse between pages..

Comment: Hi, i am having the same problem. Can you help me with a sample. It would be really great.