# How to get N html text that would fit a TextView

Tags: android, textview, paint

I have a big HTML string, all tags in it are supported by Html.fromHtml() ex. p, b, strong, br, i, em, a,   and some other escape characters nothing fancy. I also have some images in there, but lets just skip that cause it may get very complicated. I want to be able to to splint my string in pages with fixed base   font size. I have seen this question [Breaking large text into pages in android text switcher or view flipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225994/breaking-large-text-into-pages-in-android-text-switcher-or-view-flipper) that uses Paint.breakText() and TextView.getLineHeight(), the solution is very nice and works pretty much well with plain text. How do I achieve the same with simple html?

Comment: i am unable to understand your question......what are you trying to do??show a pre loaded html page in  an xml webview??or something else

Comment: I am trying to break a string with html into multiple strings (pages) to be shown in different textviews. Each TextView represents a single page

Comment: have you tried saving the html file??and then fetching the content out of it??you will have to dynamically add text views i guess to maintain flexibility of the app

Comment: if you are good at file handling then you can try this approach